XPath search with text containing soft hyphen
/div[contains(text(),"Inverter")]

This is the code that we currently used to map some objects in selenium with xpath. The problem now is, that they introduced soft hyphens now into their code and the text "Inverter" now is "In­ver­t­er".
I already tried a little around with translate and replace but did not manage to make it work so it can still find it.
Does anyone know how I can / should adapt my xpath query so I can continue with the text mapping?
Some things that I have already tried same with translate and replace but it doesn't seem to work:
/div[contains(translate(text(),"\u00AD",""),"Inverter")]
/div[contains(translate(text(),"&shy;",""),"Inverter")]
/div[contains(translate(text(),"-",""),"Inverter")]


post the url or the html.

since text() gets displayed text you might need XPATH with an OR for "Inverter" and "Inver-ter". The soft-hypen itself will probably not exist for display.  You might just run a quick test and get value of element.text() for an element with ­ in it.

Please make it clear what change is done, it is not clear after reading this, from your question: and the text "Inverter" now is "In­ver­t­er".

You have two issues here:

how to include the "soft-hyphen" character in your XPath expression
how to identify the div elements containing the character string

The first one will depend on your host language (JavaScript, python, Java? you don't say). Your best bet may be to paste the actual character into your code (though it may not be visible, so worth adding a comment so it doesn't just appear to be a null string). NB the &shy; notation is part of HTML; if your code was JS included within a <script> element in an HTML page that might work, but otherwise I wouldn't expect it to. It's not part of XPath. There's no way in XPath 1.0 to specify a character by Unicode codepoint or anything (though there is in XPath 2.0 and later).
The second issue is about identifying the div. I assume you want a div which contains the target string anywhere within it, but that's not what your XPath does:
/div[contains(translate(text(),"-",""),"Inverter")]

Firstly, the leading / identifies the document node, so /div means you are searching for a div element which is a direct child of the document node, which of course it probably isn't (I guess your root element will be html). If your XPath starts with //div or /descendant::div then your search will traverse the entire document.
Secondly, note that the text() expression there is interpreted relative to the div element; and without an explicit axis specifier, it's short-hand for child::text(), so it will only include text nodes which are direct children of the div, and won't include text nodes nested inside p or whatever elements. Note also that although the text() expression will return the set of all child text nodes, in XPath 1.0 the translate() function will convert that set of text nodes into a string, by taking the text value of the first of those nodes, only.
To search for all text() nodes within the div, you could use this expression:
//div[descendant::text()[contains(translate(.,"-",""),"Inverter")]]

Or alternatively, and more simply: you could search within the string value of the entire div element:
//div[contains(translate(.,"-",""),"Inverter")]

Here, the . refers to the context node, which is the div. Passing the div to the translate function will first extract the text content of the entire div, which is defined to the concatenation of all of its descendant text nodes.

I think you should use replace() because translate() just cuts. And if you specify that you want to replace the hyphen that you denote with spaces " - " and replace it with a single space " " to prevent text merging, the hyphen will stay inside the word because there are no spaces inside the word before and after the hyphen. If that doesn't work, try swapping the spaces around:
replace(//div[contains(.,"Inver-ter ") or contains(.,"Inverter ")], " - ", " ")

If you have the ability to use xpath 2, you can develop this idea on your platform:
for $x in //div[contains(.,"Inver-ter")], $y in //div[contains(.,"Inverter")]  
return 
if(substring-after(substring-before($x, "ter"), "Inver") = "-") 
then(translate($x, "\u00AD", "") or translate($x, "&shy;", "")) 
else if($y) then(translate($y, "\u00AD", "") or translate($y, "&shy;", "") or translate($y, "-", "")) 
else()

